# Multiple subdomains--for multiple clients-- go to same web application

Tags: php, apache, drupal

I have developed a web application (in Drupal) which supports multiple client organizations.  I have everything working, they just need to visit mydomain.com, log in, and the software knows which organization they belong to, and it gets themed with their branding, settings, and shows their data.  All of that is working.

My question is:

Is there a way to set up a subdomain for each organization, **that stays in the address bar**, but is using the same code?

```
Ex:  org1.mydomain.com  => /var/www/index.php
     org2.mydomain.com  => /var/www/index.php
```

This would make the clients really feel like they have their own unique server experience, even though they are all logging in to the same application.

Thanks!

Comment: Isn't this just a VirtualHost for each client pointing to the same root directory?

Comment: Yeah it is-- I'm dumb.  I was way overthinking it.  I'll post an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welp, I'm dumb.  I was overthinking the problem, and once I tested out a few things, it's very simple.

Have your VirtualHost entry have multiple "ServerAlias" addresses for your different subdomains.  Ex:

```
<virtualhost *:80>
   ServerName org.example.com
   ServerAlias org1.example.com org2.example.com
```

That's pretty much it.  The subdomain the user went to will stay in the address bar

**Some tips:**

A) In your web application, make sure to always use relative URLs and paths.

B) Use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] to detect which subdomain you're on, for branding or what-have-you.

**For Drupal:**

edit the sites.php and make sure the new subdomain points to the same sites directory, if using multisites.